# Mysql queries over remote connection to DB

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant

For development, I'm using vagrant with a remote MySQL db on my internal network that I connect to with a vpn if I'm external.

I have a process that executes ~2000 queries. When I'm developing with this process over vpn, a single query can take about .3 seconds to run which means the entire process would take 10 minutes if the ajax call didn't crash first.

Running this on the production server takes less than 10 seconds.

This question is two parts.

1. Can I optimize the connection between the vagrant and the remote database so each query is faster.

and/or

2. Can I optimize the process to require less queries?

For question 2, the process involves inserting a record into a mail table and then updating a record in another table inside a loop so these two queries happen about 1000 times each. I'm currently preparing the statements outside the loop and executing inside. I've tried using a transaction with auto commit turned off.

```
//Insert query
INSERT INTO emails
(
     email,
     subject,
     html
)
VALUES
(
     :email,
     :title,
     :html_message
)

//Update query
UPDATE
    details
SET
    email_sent_date = :sent_date,
    unique_val = :val
WHERE
    id = :id
```

Comment: Remote connections suffer pretty badly from latency and packet loss. Can you make a small API that can, for example, receive a large JSON payload and run the necessary calls on your server more quickly?

Comment: It sounds a bit strange though that you're required to use a remote MySQL connection on your dev box. I'd strongly suggest creating db migration files so you can start up a dev box with a dev db as well.

Comment: @JimL it's a long term plan but right now we have a huge amount of data and sensitive customer data too which makes it complicated. Also we don't usually run into problems like this and therefore never really face the urgent need to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing separate queries in a loop, try to combine them into single queries. For `INSERT`, you can use multiple lists of values:

```
INSERT INTO emails (email, subject, html)
VALUES (:email1, :subject1, :html1), (:email2, :subject2, :html2), ...
```

And for `UPDATE` you can use conditional assignments.

```
UPDATE details
SET email_sent = CASE id
    WHEN :id1 THEN :sent_date1
    WHEN :id2 THEN :sent_date2
    ...
END,
    unique_val = CASE id
    WHEN :id1 THEN :val1
    WHEN :id2 THEN :val2
    ...
END
WHERE id IN (:id1, :id2, ...)
```

You should be able to generate these queries and the associative arrays of parameters dynamically from the input data.

Comment: I tried the INSERT one and was able to do that successfully but I never found a way to do the UPDATE. I'll try your method using the `END` keyword.

Comment: The `END` keyword is just part of a `CASE` exxpression.

Comment: Ah, there I see it. I'll give this a shot

Comment: So this ended up still not working and I'm not completely sure why. The script died and I got a 503 error after a minute. In the end I bit the bullet and set up a local db. Once that was done I got an error about the `max_allowed_packet` size but since I can develop completely locally now I'll switch this back to prepared statements in a loop. Thanks for the help though.